Device for switching between laptop and PC Tower

Hello all, I am considering replacing my laptop with a PC Tower (desktop), but my setup will need to continue to support my work laptop.
The diagram below roughly shows the setup I need.
I am unsure what the device on the top right in the diagram should be.
What is that device called?
Are there any recommendations from anyone who has a similar setup?
The requirements are:

seamless switching without any cable setup changes
support laptop and PC tower
quick switch, no delay or with minimal delay
support USB ports, wired ethernet cable ports, wired peripherals and Bluetooth devices (possibly USB port will cover this)

Thank you.

Hi dushyantp, could you specify: 1. Which monitors you're using 2. What OSs you're running on the tower/laptop 3. What Bluetooth headset you're using? The traditional solution would be a KVM, but there may be free and equivalently-functional software-based alternatives depending on what you're running

Hi @JMY1000, I am using HP Z24 G2 monitors, Win 11 OS and MS Surface Headphones. If you are aware of a software solution, please let me know.

Consider using haimgel/display-switch and a generic USB switch
Good traditional KVMs are expensive. While cheaper KVMs do exist, they often come with significant compromises or bugs. An inexpensive, robust solution is to use this software! It watches for USB device connect/disconnect events and switches monitor inputs via DDC/CI, turning a cheap USB switch into a KVM.

Your HP Z24 G2 monitors have both HDMI and DisplayPort inputs, with support for the full resolution and refresh rate on both ports. You can connect the laptop over one and the desktop over the other
Your keyboard, mouse, and any other USB devices can be connected via the generic USB switch, with the display-switch software taking care of the input switching.
The first-generation Microsoft Surface Headphones can unfortunately only connect with one device at a time. Because the headphones need to be connected on a per-computer basis rather than a per-Bluetooth adapter basis for full functionality, neither this solution nor a traditional KVM address this. I would recommend either:

Pairing your headphones with both devices, and switching the connection via the quick settings. It'll add a few seconds, but it's not the worst thing ever.
Upgrading the Surface Headphones 2, which can connect to up to two devices simultaneously.
Switching to wired headphones, and using either a USB DAC connected to the USB switch or a standard analog switch.




It means we need to have laptop docking station as well? All USB get connected to laptop via docking station. And ethernet cable connected to both docking station and desktop tower? I think this will work, just confirming.

No, all the USB gets connected to the USB switch (via a hub if necessary); one cable runs from the switch to the laptop, and one cable from the switch to the tower. For Ethernet, I recommend running separate connections; network switches are cheap and readily available.
